# Link to projects on java.net / kenai.com

Tags: feature-request, jobs, open-source

careers.stackoverflow.com has connectors for various hosting sites but nothing special for java.net (and the deprecated kenai.com using the same "Kenai" infrastructure). Until a connector is added, a user must manually enter projects they own on these sites, which is cumbersome.